# GNU 8085 Simulator(How to change the initial starting address)

Tags: assembly, 8085

I'm using GNUSim8085. And its default starting address is 4200H.

> How do i change this address to any custom address I want?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/gnusim8085/+question/111760

Comment: My GNUSim8085 has a "load me at" text box right above the code where you can enter any address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GNUSIm does have a load me at button on the top of the code editor windows

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Change value of **load me at** option to start your program at desired address